# Django migration issue for boolean field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have models and there was no Boolean field in the very beginning when i run `makemigraiton` and `migrate`

In that mean time, i added some post...

later i added new field called `is_printable` as boolean field...

this is my current models:

from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

## Create your models here.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        max_length=50,
    )
    is_printable = models.BooleanField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(timezone.now)
```

when i add

```
is_printable = models.BooleanField()
```

I cant run `migrate` command, it throws me an error called

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'2019-07-07 06:56:52.693378+00:00' value must be either True or False."]
```

What is possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you added is_printable field and ran makemigrations Django would've asked you to enter default value for the newly added field, what is the default value you gave? I presume you gave timezone.now() and because of that it would've thrown error during migrate.